# How to stream an html string to browser within a MVC 6 controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to write the following custom `ActionResult` but when I visit action `URL` in browser, it is a white page and nothings send to browser.

```
internal class HtmlStreamActionResult : IActionResult
{
    private string _text = "";
    public HtmlStreamActionResult(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var rr = new HttpResponseStreamWriter(_text.ToStream(), UTF8Encoding.Unicode);

        return Task.FromResult(_text.ToStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious, is this html string the whole html document? how is it generated ? Also can you use `ContentResult` instead...just set make sure to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html`.

Comment: did you add a route for the url? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debugging to see if your code is reached/executed?

Comment: fyi as of beta7 a 404 can result in a blank white page unless you opt in to IIS pipeline app.RunIISPipeline(); https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/54 that is why I asked if you have a route configured. it is not clear if your code is being executed.

Comment: the other way to prevent a blank page for 404 besides opting in to IIS pipeline is app.UseStatusCodePages();

Comment: Thanks @JoeAudette for your helpful hints.

Comment: I recommend this example of streaming data in MVC6: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/custom-actionresult-aspnet5-mvc6